# Ruby on Rails 4: Polymorphic Association throws InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError

Tags: database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Two tables are having a has_one relationship to another table »Feedbacks« via polymorphic associations.

```
# Class Request
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :requests
  has_one :feedback, as: :feedbackable
end

# Class Acceptance
class Acceptance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :acceptances
  has_one :feedback, as: :feedbackable
end

# Class Feedback
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :feedbackable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :feedbacks
end
```

However, when trying to create a feedback associated to either requests or acceptances, the console throws me the error. Here's how I tried to create a feedback:

```
# First way
feedback = request.create_feedback(user_id: 2, message: "Hey, good driver!")

# Second way
feedback = Feedback.create(user_id: 1, message: "Hey, good driver!") 
#user_id describes the user the feedback addresses

request = Request.create(user_id: 2)
#user_id describes the user the request comes from

request.feedback = feedback
```

This is the error that gets thrown:

> ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the
>   inverse association for feedback (:request in Feedback)

Thanks in advance, I've been search everywhere and didn't find a similar problem :S

You might want to know what my database looks like:

```
class CreateAcceptances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :acceptances do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :requests do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateFeedbacks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :feedbacks do |t|
      t.references :feedbackable, polymorphic: true
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.string :message
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the code you've posted exactly what is being run to generate that error message?  Based on the error I would have expected the following Request code:

```
# Class Request
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :requests
  has_one :feedback, as: :feedbackable, inverse_of: :request
end
```

Specifically that you were telling another activerecord to look inside Feedback for a :request association that it wasn't finding `has_one :feedback, inverse_of: :request`. This could be on any activerecord model, not necessarily request.rb. I ran into this exact same message in Rails 4.0.2 and removing the inverse_of: resolved the issue.